# M3 SKY Barcode Read in c#

Tags: c#, .net, compact-framework

I want to read barcode data into a TextBox in an application running on an [M3 SKY](http://www.m3mobile.net/products/products_view.asp?s1=1&s2=5&s3=33) handheld device (Windows Mobile 6.1).

I am using .NET Compact Framework 3.5 and C#. I couldn't find any library to do this.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not familiar with the M3 device, but if it works like every other handheld barcode scanner running a Windows CE-based OS, then the scanner should work as a keyboard wedge.  Basically when you scan a barcode, your application will get keyboard data.

The easiest mechanism to test that is to put a TextBox on a Form, *give the TextBox Focus*, and then scan a barcode.  If that works, then there you have it.  You might want to do some work turning on `KeyPreview` so you don't have to force the focus in your app all the time, but that's the general process.